# solr dataimport: unable to get datasource connection but command stays "busy"

Tags: python, solr, dataimporthandler

We have a solr instance with a DataImportHandler that is configured with a JdbcDataSource to import it's data. Works fine most of the times, but sometimes it cannot create the connection. It happens during the following scenario:

In our spring application we have a scheduler that makes a rest call to solr to initiate a delta import (every 12 hours). We see this request in the solr logs, data-config.xml is loaded, delta import is started. This is where logging stops. Nothing else related to the import job is logged. When we ask the status of the import we find "status": "busy" and "Total Requests made to DataSource": "0".

And this is the annoying part. The job stays busy for hours, even days, and never completes or fails. This also stops other dataimport calls from our scheduler, as the previous job is still "busy". I would hope that solr would realise that something is wrong and would exit the job with some error status or something. I don't want one job that does nothing to block next import requests, when perhaps the database is available again.

I cannot find what I could tweak in our solr instance to make sure the job actually completes/fails instead of being busy doing nothing for days. Anyone any ideas? Need to see any config examples? Not sure what I would need to show as the setup is working most of the time.

The only thing that is logged about the dataimport, after this the import is not mentioned anymore:

```
651589 INFO  (qtp668849042-19) [   x:myCore] o.a.s.h.d.DataImporter Loading DIH Configuration: data-config.xml
651655 INFO  (qtp668849042-19) [   x:myCore] o.a.s.h.d.DataImporter Data Configuration loaded successfully
651700 INFO  (qtp668849042-19) [   x:myCore] o.a.s.c.S.Request [myCore] webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={optimize=true&commit=true&clean=false&wt=json&command=delta-import} status=0 QTime=118 
651711 INFO  (Thread-21) [   x:myCore] o.a.s.h.d.DataImporter Starting Delta Import
651799 INFO  (Thread-21) [   x:myCore] o.a.s.h.d.SimplePropertiesWriter Read dataimport.properties
651914 INFO  (Thread-21) [   x:myCore] o.a.s.h.d.DocBuilder Starting delta collection.
```

[image: Job keeps running but executes nothing]

Comment: what is the DB? maybe try setting some param in the jdbc connection string to force an error (some timeout? might depend on the db)

Comment: Oracle and MySQL. We gather data from both, and both have the same issue.